# Sending a string from a Javascript client to a Python server(without the use of a Web Framework)?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension, webserver

I want to send a url from a chrome extension to a python server. I am currently working with the websockets and asyncio modules on python and the WebSocket for Javascript but whenever my python server receives anything it just says 'undefined.' Anyways, I do not want to use a Web Framework, a lot of the answers to this kind of question I have seen use Web Frameworks which I would like to avoid as much as possible. Here is my current Python code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"< {name}")
start_server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 12345)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

And here is my Javascript code:

```
var websocket;
var url;
var data;
websocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:12345");
websocket.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", sendUrl());

function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}

function sendUrl() {
  chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    url = tabs[0].url;
    data = encode_utf8(url)
    console.log(url);
  });

  websocket.onopen = () => websocket.send(data);
}
```

Comment: Your first `sendUrl()` is invoking the function. Remove `()` so that it becomes a proper reference. Also, if this is inside a content script, you can't use chrome.tabs there - simply use `location.href`.